# How to merge text file vertically?

Tags: paste

Let's assume that I've got two text file a, b.

```
$cat a
a a
a a
a a

$cat b
b b
b b
b b
```

Then, I want to merge these two file vertically by using paste. The merged file is shown bellow

```
a a
a a
a a
b b
b b
b b
```

NOT

```
$paste a b > AB
$cat AB
a a b b
a a b b
a a b b
```

Comment: "The merged file will be b" should be changed "The merged file will be below". I don't know how to modify.

Comment: `paste -sd '\n' a b`

Comment: You mean something like `cat a.txt b.txt`? To edit your question just press edit under your question

Comment: `cat` is short for concatenate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just `cat a.txt b.txt > out.txt`. If you want even spaces and no blank lines

```
$ awk 'NF' inputA.txt inputB.txt                           
a a
a a
a a
b b
b b
b b
```